# Enable Flexbox Grid Using Bootstrap 4 Alpha CDN

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

Hey guys I am just wondering how I can enable Flexbox grid for Bootstrap 4 when I am using the CDN?

Usually I would use NPM and include the Flexbox Sass file and import them into my base Bootstrap Sass file.

I can't think of any way I could do this with the CDN version.

Any help would be great.

Comment: you do not want to use the CDN that provides the bootstrap css with Flexbox enabled?

Comment: AFAIK, there is not currently a flexbox enabled version available on CDN

Comment: @ZimSystem how about [this](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap-flex.min.css)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no CDN version of Bootstrap Flex Grid available till now.

But it seems that [**scotch.io**](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/whats-new-in-bootstrap-4) has already released the compiled version of Bootstrap 4 (Flex CSS).

Hope this helps!